# What is the difference with People-centered design (PCD), User-centered design (UCD) and Human-centered design (HCD)?

Tags: user-centered-design

So I've noticed many people mention these 3 approaches:

- People-centered design (PCD)
- User-centered design (UCD)
- Human-centered design (HCD)

I have been researching and I only found a good article in which they explain the difference between **UCD** and **HCD**. I will leave it here: https://www.digital-adoption.com/user-centered-design-vs-human-centered-design/

But then, **what is the difference with People-centered design (PCD)** and **User-centered design (UCD)**?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: I would say it depends on what your definition of People, User and Human are :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not heard of the term People-Centred Design, but I would be very surprised if there is much difference between People and Human.

As far as User versus People/Human, the term user is normally defined as being the subset of the population that use the product or service provided. Sometimes there is also a subset of users defined as being Customers or Clients (who are paying for the product or service), hence the term Customer Experience Design.

Regardless of what the exact term is, the key is the actual definition that you apply to whichever term that you are using.